# Wordpress: linking page to menu item doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and followed instructions to link a page to a menu item but it's not working.  I go to *Dashboard>Appearance>Menus*.  I check the About page on the left and click *Add to Menu*.  It shows up on the right.  I click *Save Menu*.

[image]I go to the main site ([www.tekknow.net](http://www.tekknow.net)), click on the About menu item, and it says "This page isn't working".  Suggestions?

**EDIT**: The field values in Settings > General are

```
Wordpress Address (URL): http://tekknow.net
Site Address (URL): http://tekknow.net
```

The permalink setting is now set to Post Name and the About menu item now shows tekknow.net/about in the URL but still getting error.  This time error is "This page isn't working - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".  I googled that error and found this informative page: https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/  but nothing I tried would fix it.

I've cleared the cookies, deactivated all plugins, can see no redirect to HTTP or https in the .htaccess file, resaved the permalinks, yet the error persists.

Please help!

Comment: Is your server running on windows?

Comment: The error isn't "This page isn't working" it's "This page isn't redirecting properly" which is entirely different. If you look at your URL, it's trying to access `/index.php/about` Which will  never resolve. How are your permalinks set up?

Comment: No, the server is running on Ubuntu 18.04.  The message on my chrome browser says "This page isn't working".  If I change the url to tekknow.net/about it then says "OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN'T BE FOUND."  Where can I find the permalinks?  I did not set them, wordpress did.

Comment: Under settings, you can find permalinks. What is selected there?

Comment: Custom Structure is selected (I didn't do that) with the following entered in the field: /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my HostGator support and they solved the problem.  Had to delete the About page, recreate it, re-add it to the menu.  Then it worked!  Something about the original About page that came with the twentyseventeen theme that it didn't like.  Horrible first experience with WordPress.